# задать значение объекту

Tags: typescript

как задать значение свойству `name`?

> Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Item'. Property 'created' is missing in type '{ name: string; }'.

```js
export class Items extends BaseModelVersion {
  name: string;
}

export class ItemsComponent {
  item: Items = {
    name: 'items_name'
  };

  items: Items[] = [this.item];
}
```

Comment: дайте код класса `Items`. Как вариант можно сделать конструктор, и передавай в него `name`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц,  самая первая строка - экспортируемый класс `Items`. Или какой код вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Оу.. ас слона то я и не заметил, прошу прощения

Comment: item: Items = new Items(); item.name = "asd";

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, пишет `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'item'. TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'item' must be of type 'Items', but here has type 'any'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У тебя не хватает обязательного поля `created` из `BaseModelVersion`.
2. Объект - не функция, у тебя в `this.item` какой-то мусор (вероятно вообще нет такого поля).

Comment: @Qwerty, спасибо. Уже разобралась, но ваш ответ правильный